# Change column pattern R

Tags: r

I don't know how to call the pattern of column but
I have column like this

```
Gene         value1     value2
A              10          5
B              52         23
C              14          9
```

I want to change pattern of columns to be like this

```
Gene        Type       Value
A          value1        10      
A          value2         5
B          value1        52
B          value2        23
C          value1        14
C          value2         9
```

Mostly, in ggplot2 always apply this pattern of column in plotting
so I am wondering how to write code in R

Thank you in advanced :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` to put the data into long form.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Gene, names_to = "Type", values_to = "Value")
```

**Output**

```
  Gene  Type   Value
  <chr> <chr>  <int>
1 A     value1    10
2 A     value2     5
3 B     value1    52
4 B     value2    23
5 C     value1    14
6 C     value2     9
```

Or with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)

melt(dt, id.vars = "Gene", variable.name = "Type", value.name = "Value")
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Gene = c("A", "B", "C"), value1 = c(10L, 52L, 
14L), value2 = c(5L, 23L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: That worked for me. Thank you for your answer and sorry for the late response

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, the desired transformation can also be obtained in base R with `reshape` function:

```
# Sample data
dta <- read.table(text = "Gene         value1     value2
A              10          5
B              52         23
C              14          9",  header = TRUE)

# Transformation
reshape(
    data = dta,
    direction = "long",
    idvar = "Gene",
    varying = c("value1", "value2"),
    v.names = "Value",
    timevar = "Type",
    times = c("value1", "value2")
)
```

### Outcome

```
         Gene   Type Value
A.value1    A value1    10
B.value1    B value1    52
C.value1    C value1    14
A.value2    A value2     5
B.value2    B value2    23
C.value2    C value2     9
```